# React useEffect: react on a value change to update another one who's also a dependency

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

I have a view that is a big paginated table.
I want to include the page index in the URL query params to be able to share a specific page of the table by sharing the URL.

My problem is that the page isn't the only query param, so what I need to do is, when a page change:

1. Retrieve the current query params
2. Create the new query params from the old ones and the new page
3. Update the query params.

However, updating the query params is a problem, because the query params are a dependency of the function that retrieves the old ones and I am stuck in this loop.

I first tried to do something like this:

```js
import query from 'qs'
import { useLocation, useHistory } from 'react-router-dom'

function Comp() {
  const [pageIndex, setPageIndex] = useState(0)

  // Updates the query params using the provided ones.
  const updateQueryParams = useCallback(
    (pageIndex) => {
      const oldSearch = query.parse(location.search, { ignoreQueryPrefix: true })
      const newSearch = { ...oldSearch, pageIndex }
      history.push({ pathname: location.pathname, search: query.stringify(newSearch) })
    },
    [location.search, location.pathname]
  )

  // Updates the query params when pageIndex changes.
  useEffect(() => updateQueryParams(pageIndex), [updateQueryParams, pageIndex])
}
```

But updating the query params updates `location.search` which is a dependency of the `updateQueryParams` callback and it triggers an infinite loop.

I tried to make use of `useRef` to store the search and the pathname, updating them manually, but I've been unable to come up to a working solution.

My last try was to extract the logic in a custom hook to cut the problem in smaller pieces (and I will have to reuse this piece of logic elsewhere).

The current state of this hook is:

```js
import { useLocation, useHistory } from 'react-router-dom'
import { useRef, useCallback } from 'react'
import query from 'qs'

export default function useQueryParams<QueryParams extends query.ParsedQs>(): [
  QueryParams,
  (newSearch: QueryParams) => void
] {
  const location = useLocation()
  const history = useHistory()

  const search = useRef(query.parse(location.search, { ignoreQueryPrefix: true }) as QueryParams)
  const pathname = useRef(location.pathname)

  const setSearch = useCallback(
    (newSearch: QueryParams) => {
      history.push({ pathname: pathname.current, search: query.stringify(newSearch) })
      search.current = newSearch
    },
    [history, pathname]
  )

  return [search.current, setSearch]
}
```

But it doesn't solve my problem.
Trying to access the route triggers an infinite loop and I get a `Warning: Maximum update depth exceeded` error in the console.

Comment: is this what you want https://xperiome.raremark.com/studies check the filters. If so i can help you on that

Comment: if you remove `updateQueryParams` from useEffect, will it fix?

Comment: @Monzoor Tamal yes this is the kind of thing I try to do. The thing is thatI try to do it reactively rather than imperatively. I don't update the query params in the function that handle the user interaction but through a useEffect. My goal is to have a re-usable piece of logic.

Comment: @Alan Yong I stick to what the linter says me to do concerning the dependency. I am relatively new to React but from my understanding the linter is probably always right and there is a proper way to handle this kind of case.

Comment: @CédricRémond you can ignore linter to test first.

Comment: eg: 
`useEffect(() => {
    getData();
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, [id]);`

Comment: @AlanYong No it doesn't solve the issue :/

Comment: Did you find solution for this infinite loop ;| ?

Comment: @sumeet Yes, but this is very particular to this context, I'll post it right now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was caused by how my routes was declared.

The solution has been to update all my routes from this pattern:

```
<Route path="/login" component={Login} />
```

to this one:

```
<Route path="/login">
    <Login />
</Route>
```